# How to mock protected virtual members with Rhino.Mocks?

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks, moq

[Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) allows developers to mock protected members.  I was looking for the same functionality in [Rhino.Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) but fail to find it.

Here's an example from [Moq Quick Start](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) page how to mock protected method.

```
// at the top of the test fixture
using Moq.Protected()

// in the test
var mock = new Mock<CommandBase>();
mock.Protected()
     .Setup<int>("Execute")
     .Returns(5);

// if you need argument matching, you MUST use ItExpr rather than It
// planning on improving this for vNext
mock.Protected()
    .Setup<string>("Execute",
        ItExpr.IsAny<string>())
    .Returns(true);
```

Let me know if I'm chasing something that doesn't exit.

Comment: You might want to check out this link http://geekswithblogs.net/MattRobertsBlog/archive/2008/12/16/how-to-make-a-quotprotectedquot-method-available-for-quotpartialquot-mocking-and-again.aspx

Comment: That's not really a suitable solution - having to change your original class to expose a method internally to other classes means you are altering your design to cater for testing. Bad smell for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this functionality does not exist in Rhino Mocks.

Why are you trying to mock protected members? Why not just test the class as a whole? Alternatively you can create a subclass of your test class and create "mocked" protected methods manually.

Comment: I'm currently subclassing SUT and mock the protected member.  I was wondering if there's something like in Moq that would save me from subclassing.  I'll accept your answer, assuming that Rhino.Mocks doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: Because Microsoft has things like this now. ...
protected internal virtual OkResult Ok()
{
}

Answer (score 2):

We create the `protected` method as `internal`, and then expose the internals to the unit testing project and rhino mocks by adding the following lines to your AssemblyInfo:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourNamespace.TestProjectName")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

works a treat for us

Comment: keith, thanks but I was looking for some other solution then modifying my AssemblyInfo.  
BTW.  About 5 years ago I created a utility that generates InternalVisibleTo code for you.  It might save you some time. You can find it here: http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2007/12/09/testing-internals-members-with-internalsvisibleto-attribute/

Comment: @Vadim nice thanks man, I believe VS2012 allows you to mock anything so this problem might not exist for the next generation of unit tests!