# Is it possible to test an internal virtual method using StructureMap.AutoMocking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, structuremap, rhino-mocks

Is it possible to use the auto mocking framework provided in StructureMap.AutoMocking to test an internal virtual method within the CUT?  I have already added InternalsVisibleTo to the appropriate AssemblyInfo.cs files.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public ClassA {
    public void Method1() { Method2(); }
    internal virtual void Method2() { /* do work */ }
}

[Test]
public void TestClassA() {

    // Arrange
    var mockedClass = new RhinoAutoMocker<ClassA>();
    mockedClass.PartialMockTheClassUnderTest();
    mockedClass.ClassUnderTest.Expect(x => x.Method2());

    // Act
    mockedClass.ClassUnderTest.Method1();

    // Assert
    mockedClass.ClassUnderTest.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

I already know that changing the internal method to public works, but I don't feel that this is an acceptable way to perform this test.  Perhaps I am missing something fundamental about the way RhinoMocks and StructureMap interact but I figured based on other unit tests I've written that this type of thing should work.

**Edit** I suppose it would help to provide the error message I get when I try this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call       
has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) 
method).
at Rhino.Mocks.LastCall.GetOptions()
at Rhino.Mocks.RhinoMocksExtensions.Expect(T mock, Func`2 action)
at Rhino.Mocks.RhinoMocksExtensions.Expect(T mock, Action`1 action)
at ClassATest.TestClassA() in ClassA.cs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
I am wrong in my below statements.  I finally circled back to this and used the keyword `protected` on all of my unit tests that were testing `internal virtual` methods within my class under test.  This **DOES** work in structure map and is the only reason why I was receiving the error I was receiving.

<del>After a bit of research on this, there seems to be some elements of Rhino.Mocks that are not accessible via StructureMap.Automocker.  When I re-worked my unit tests to make use of only the Rhino.Mocks framework, I was able to expose `internal virtual` methods to the test runner.   Not an ideal situation and I would like to see support for this in newer versions of StructureMap, but that may be a long way off if there's other more important things that precede adding support for `internal virtual` methods.</del>

I re-worked my unit tests based on the following posts:

http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+-+Internal+Methods.ashx

[How to mock protected virtual members with Rhino.Mocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581052/how-to-mock-protected-virtual-members-with-rhino-mocks)